# Visual Studio One-Click Deployment "succeeds", but no files publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, one-click-web-publishing

Here is the output after the build/web.config transformation:

```
Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.
Publishing folder /...
Site was published successfully path_goes_here
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

yet when it loads the root folder, nothing is there. Going to the site gives a Server Error of

```
401 - unauthorized: access is denied due to invalid credentials
```

understandable considering nothing is in that directory, I believe. If possibly misleading.

To work around this issue, I copied and pasted the release of the deployment server to the production server. I didn't have access issues doing this so I don't believe it was preventing me from deploying due to permissions.

How do I troubleshoot this particular scenario?

Comment: I have a similar issue -  deployment runs as normal but specified folder is empty? Have you had any progress?

Comment: None. Though I'm unable to touch the IIS (well, the server in general) part to see if it may be a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following which had worked for other people, hopefully one may work for you:

Publish as release, then go back and publish as debug again.

Publish as web deploy package then go back and publish to filesystem.

Reinstalling VS2012=0 worked until an update upgraded my Publish dialog.

None worked for me though, so the workaround I came up with is to publish as web deploy package - which actually contains the files that would be in the file system folder - get the files (from the PackageTmp folder) and deploy as before.

I found that a DLL reference was missing from one of the projects but I fixed that by adding it, unused, to the start up project, which causes it to be recognised and published.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it with /A:Basic, worked for me

/A:
    Specifies the type of authentication to be used. The possible values are NTLM and Basic. If the wmsvc provider setting is specified, the default authentication type is Basic; otherwise, the default authentication type is NTLM.